# lastwritetime is changing while extracting a zipfile in c#?

Tags: c#

While extracting a winzip file through code,Lastwritetime is changing in seconds...

Actual file Lastwritetime:`4/8/2010 2:29:`03`PM`
After zipping that file using winzip and while extracting that file using the code,actual files Lastwritetime changes to `4/8/2010 2:29:`04`PM`...Is there any fix for this???
Here is my code...

```
                Chilkat.Zip zip = new Chilkat.Zip();
                bool unlocked = zip.UnlockComponent("30-day trial");
                if (!unlocked)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(zip.LastErrorText);
                    return;
                }

                bool success = zip.OpenZip(inputFolderPath);
                if (!success)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(zip.LastErrorText);
                    return;
                }
                long count = zip.Unzip(outputFolderPath);
                if (count == -1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(zip.LastErrorText);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Unzipped Successfully!");

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be an issue with the zip library itself. try using sharpZiplib, i've used it a couple of times and works like a charm. http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/Download.aspx

Comment: But it is extracting files with current datetime

Comment: Are you saying that if you extract it is changing the lastwritetime to the time it is extracted? If so then you can always go change those values with File.SetLastWriteTime(path, lastWriteTime) where lastWriteTime is a datetime

Comment: Look at my edit where i have to give File.SetLastWriteTime(path, lastWriteTime) and how to change this...can u edit mine

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an issue with the library code. Try contacting the vendor to see if they can fix it or alternatively switch to another component. If you don't need a managed solution and want faster compression you can try a native solution like Bricolsoft Zip ActiveX. http://www.bricolsoft.com/zip-activex-component.html.